# Eclipse git - unable to clone - git: not authorized error

Tags: eclipse, clone, egit

Recently my windows OS was reinstalled.
Before that, in my eclipse, clone was working without any issues. Now with fresh Eclipse, as I try to clone I get the error(attached images). Not sure what is missing.
I tried to add http.sslVerify=false and it is not working out.
In the browser I could see the repository and it is fine.
I also have 'Git' in my machine, through which I'm able to clone the repository! What could be issue when I do this via eclipse?

[Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOhA7.png)
[More details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyZgX.png)

Comment: Your Eclipse is pretty old. Please upgrade.

Comment: I upgraded to Eclipse Version: 2020-12 (4.18.0)
Build id: 20201210-1552. Still facing the same issue.

Comment: Did you also update EGit/JGit? Which version of EGit/JGit do you have? The screenshots still shows your retro Eclipse.

Comment: Updated screenshots for your reference. Eclipse version : 2020-06 (4.16.0)
Build id: 20200615-1200, 

EGIT Version - 5.8.0.202006091008-r

Comment: That's both two releases behind. Please check before you ask if you haven't missed to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

In bitbucket 'settings', there is an option called 'app passwords' under 'Access Management'. There I created a password and used that password in eclipse during clone, solved my problem!